# Direct3D: should I use MIXED_VERTEXPROCESSING?

Tags: directx, rendering, vertex

Yesterday on Youtube I watched a video tutorial about creating Direct3D stuff. On that tutorial there was a part about `VERTEXPROCESSING` compatibility with older video cards. The guy said that the compatibility can be checked by this code:

```
D3DDISPLAYMODE         d3ddm;
D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS  d3dp;
D3DCAPS9               d3dc;
int VP;

d3d->GetDeviceCaps(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, D3DDEVTYPE_HAL, &d3dc);
if (d3dc.DevCaps & D3DDEVCAPS_HWTRANSFORMANDLIGHT)
    VP = D3DCREATE_HARDWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING;
else
    VP = D3DCREATE_SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING;

//and then:
d3d->CreateDevice(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT,
                  D3DDEVTYPE_HAL,
                  dxhwnd,
                  VP,
                  &d3dp,
                  &d3ddev);
```

But hey OpenGL does this stuff automatically so there must be a way to achieve that easier. So today I found that this can be done by `D3DCREATE_MIXED_VERTEXPROCESSING`. But on some forums I have read that some (most older) video cards can have problems with this mode. So is there any reason why should I or shouldn't use Mixed Vertex Processing instead of using them both but with `D3DDEVCAPS`?

Comment: always use D3DDEVCAPS, it´s a querry which has been supported since the dawn of dinosaurs almost.

Comment: So basically using `D3D CREATE MIXED VERTEX PROCESSING`can cause some incompatibility on selected older or maybe even newer cards?

Comment: No, MIXED is just...weird. You can switch HW processing on/off; why anyone would I don't know. I guess it might be important if you used 32-bit indices on a dinosaur that only supported 16-bit indices, but majority of the data used 16-bit indices -- then you'd need to switch to SWVP to render the 32-bit indices and HWVP (for performance) on the 16-bit indices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Video cards without hardware T&L are dinosaurs.  Seriously, there haven't been any new cards without hardware T&L since about 2000.  Forget about them, just use hardware vertex processing and assume it's supported - unless you *specifically* need to support 14-year-old cards for some reason.

Comment: Amen to this. D3D9 doesn't make this easy for some reason. You get either HW or SW, but have to specify which. I don't know why they couldn't have just said "well, if HW is available let's use it, otherwise, software VP". I guess it is because some ancient cards at the time had restrictions (and exposed other caps) if T&L was enabled?